# Routes doesn't Link to js file - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning reactjs front-end at the moment. But I am stuck that the Routes is not working.
I'm using `ReactJS version 18.0.0`

My App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">
      <h3 className="d-flex justify-content-center m-3">
        React JS Frontend
      </h3>
        
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item- m-1">
            <NavLink className="btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" to="/home">
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then my Home.js:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>This is Home page</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Need advice please.
Thank you.

Comment: Try to replace in `Route` component -> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the `component` prop for your `Route` with an older version of `react-router`.

Change it to `element` like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/home' element={Home} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Yes, to be honest. I just learning right today. Any suggestion to understand on each version?

Comment: All good man, it caught me out too when the new version came out. I'd suggest you just be mindful of what version you have installed versus what version of the docs that you're reading.